# Why doesnt rep from SE network count towards meta for some things?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have accrued better than top 5% in one site. Here on the site that discusses mechanics and operation of that site and others, I don't have the simple option to downvote a post because the "association bonus" rep is below that threshold.

A specific example is the MIT license changeover. It overwhelmingly affects Stack Overflow where I have plenty of rep points, yet the thread was moved to this site where I do not have enough to record a downvote.

I get that it should probably not work in the opposite direction. But I think that there should be some allowances granted in permission specifically for this and other meta sites so they take into account a member's standing on the site that is the target of discussion.

EDIT: I did search for this for a few minutes and didn't find the linked question, so I'll take that as a whoops on me.

Comment: You make a valid point regarding the MIT licensing thing. This will indeed skew the votes. Nothing we can do about that.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as I misunderstood the question at first. But do you think that participating in Stack Overflow could mean that you know network-wide policies?

Comment: Well, the licensing thing is something that foremost affects SO. Most the users of SO can only upvote here though...

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ.- Yes. Its not that I am just "participating", but participating at a significant level on a site that is primarily affected by the named policy change.

Comment: [How should low-reputation MSE users express disregard of a network-wide change?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271315/245360)

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Thanks, that is appreciated.

Comment: a far more useful contribution than simply downvoting a question to say "I disagree" would be to write a passionate and well researched answer explaining to everyone why you disagree and what you want them to do about it. That you can do regardless of rep. (And it just might get your rep to where you want it, also)

Comment: Its just clutter to repeat what others have already said.