# Meta.SE should have a lowered bar for downvoting that is equivalent to upvoting

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, meta

I have a *friend* who would like to do some down voting on SE meta. This *friend* has only 88 rep on this site. However, the *friend* has also been a loyal-ish servant of SEcorp and has a reasonable reputation with some communities. I think my *friend* should therefore be allowed to downvote on the SE meta.

Therefore, copied from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271317/200228), I propose:

**Meta.SE specifically should have a lowered bar for downvoting that is equivalent to upvoting.**

Comment: And why exactly should this rule be applied to MSE only? It can't be because you're just trusted on Gardening and Landscaping that you know which network wide policies require down votes. That also requires a bit of trust that is easy obtained *here on this site*

Comment: Your *friend* could do like he did on these other communities - participate - and he'll get to >=125 rep in no time.

Comment: @rene good question - because metaSE applies across all communities

Comment: @atomh33ls so? Because MSE has more impact on all sites, all privileges should be higher, harder to achieve, not easier.

Comment: @rene my argument is that a contribution to an SE community is a contribution to SE therefore a voting on future direction is an earnt reward. That influence mightn't have been earnt for a new-user at a particular community's meta.

Comment: gah.. "an SE community" should be "a SE community"

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree, I simply don't buy that having contributed in one community should automagically give you privileges on a site that has a completely different scope. Trust needs to be earned here, that is important. A contribution in a community doesn't mean you're good at making contributions here.

Comment: @rene It may not be 500, but I'd say that there is _some number_ of rep earnt elsewhere that translates to "trust earnt here".

Comment: *elsewhere* and *here* are not synonyms and never will be and the same goes for the rep.

Comment: @rene "_X_ rep elsewhere is worth _Y_ rep here" is my argument, not that the words are synonyms!

Comment: sure, doesn't matter still disagree.

Comment: As in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273000/change-rep-required-to-downvote-on-mse?noredirect=1&lq=1) it's now only 100 rep to downvote- Not your 15 for upvoting, but much better for those who do spend time on other sites. (Well, and haven't lost the rep on posts here already... Meta can be a harsh land.)

Answer (score 12):

If you have 500 rep elsewhere, then you start out at 101 rep here. So that's 24 points you need to earn to downvote.

- Three answer upvotes
- Five question upvotes
- 12 approved suggested edits
- One upvoted and accepted answer
- Some combination of the above

Really, a trivial amount of participation.

Now... One might argue that participation sufficient to gain the association bonus elsewhere on the network should give you full voting rights here *by default* - and that's actually a reasonable argument. See: [Change rep required to downvote on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273000/change-rep-required-to-downvote-on-mse)

Comment: If you have 500 rep points on one specific SE site, you can downvote on that site's Meta. Why not here? This is Meta, ain't it? This Meta is special because it deals with issues covering the whole SE networks. Other than this, I don't see any difference from the site Meta and I don't understand why the OP's proposal is not reasonable when it is not that easy to earn reputation points here compared with other sites.

Comment: If you have 125 points on one specific SE site you can downvote on that site's Meta, @Rathony. If you have 50 points on one specific SE site, you can comment on that site's meta, Ranthony. If you have 15 points on one specific SE site, you can upvote on that site's meta, Ranthony. If you have 5 points on one specific SE site, you can post on that site's meta, Ranthony. If you have 1 point on one specific SE site, you can't really do much on that site's meta... But you can still participate here, because *it's an entirely separate site*, Ranthony. That's why.

Comment: I don't think it is an entirely separate site. It is a related site. You give 101 association bonus just because you have 200 points on another site, My question is why can't you give 125 association bonus on Meta SE when an OP has +500 reputation points on other sites? Well, I think it is very reasonable.

Comment: I think this one is also relevant; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271315/how-should-low-reputation-mse-users-express-disagreement-with-a-proposed-netwo

Comment: No, I mean it is literally a separate site, @Rathony. Separate database, normal association rules... There are a few special-cases to handle things like links and tags (mostly because of the long history in which it was MSO) and a few special privileges (of which there could be more - see the link in my answer above), but there's certainly not anything like a special reputation system such as is found on child meta sites or Area51. And as interesting as it would be to build such a thing, just tweaking the privilege level would be a hell of a lot less work for the same effect.

Comment: My point is very simple. I find giving <125 on MSE and >500 on other site users the privilege to downvote on MSE will do less harm than giving >200 users on one site the privilege to upvote on any site on entire Stack Exchange networks. I understand your point. :-)