# Why do this site's privileges' costs differ from all the other SE sites?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I know that this site is special, but I don't know why this site's privileges' costs differ so much.
For example, on this site, to comment everywhere, you need to have *5* reputation, while on every other site it takes *50* reputation to do that. Not only that, on this site, the vote down privilege costs 25 reputation less than the usual 125 reputation.
Why is this so?

Comment: Because this site is special. ;)

Comment: @yannis I know it is special. Why is it special, i guess?

Comment: why don't we have this for `talk in chat`? maybe I should write a question...

Comment: here's the link: [meta.se-2019 Why does talk in chat still require 20 reputation on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326528/why-does-talk-in-chat-still-require-20-reputation-on-meta)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this is the *Uber Meta* for the entire Stack Exchange network. To make it more accessible for relatively new users to Stack Exchange to participate, such as reporting bugs, the reputation points requirements are relaxed. (One you didn't mention: You only need 1 reputation to post here, as opposed to 5 points on a per-site Meta.)

If you look around a bit, you'll see discussions about changing these requirements, but just on this site, such as:

- [Change rep required to downvote on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273000/21960)
- [How should low-reputation MSE users express disagreement with a (proposed) network-wide change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271315/21960)

Comment: That is true ... but I didn't consider this a "meta" site in the first place

Comment: It was the original meta site, in a manner of speaking. Per site metas in a sense are a refinement on "lets just fire up another site, and see what happens"